# CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers nodejs aws error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

on my node.js app i connect to AWS DynamoDB, the top of my code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const randomId = require('random-id');
const app = express(),
      bodyParser = require("body-parser");
      port = 3080;
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
const { marshall,unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

and my config.json looks as follow (with real values that i masked here):

```
{
  "accessKeyId": "AKIA5IIKXXXXOXXXXXXK",
  "secretAccessKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
  "region": "eu-west-1"
}
```

on my local machine, the connection to DynamoDB works perfect but on my ec2 instance i get the following error:

```
    CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
    at providers (/mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist/cjs/index.js:59:19)
    at /mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/property-provider/dist/cjs/chain.js:20:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async SignatureV4.credentialProvider (/mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/property-provider/dist/cjs/memoize.js:26:26)
    at async SignatureV4.signRequest (/mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/signature-v4/dist/cjs/SignatureV4.js:84:29)
    at async /mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/cjs/middleware.js:14:22
    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/cjs/StandardRetryStrategy.js:51:46)
    at async /mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist/cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at async /mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/server.js:305:23 {
  tryNextLink: false,
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
}
```

my local machine runs a mac os and my production server runs centos 7

iv'e uploaded the files from my local computer includes node_modules and on both i use same nodejs version 14.17.5

Comment: What's happening at `/mnt/files/vhosts/Mysite/httpdocs/api/server.js:305`? Is it before or after your `AWS.config.loadFromPath` call?

Comment: not sure what you ask

Comment: The stack trace is saying that the API call on line 305 of `server.js` is failing. Is that before or after you have called `AWS.config.loadFromPath` to load the credentials?

If you're making an API call before you load the credentials, then the error is correct.